# Errai support for the GAE platform

Tags: java, google-app-engine, gwt, errai

Based on this JIRA issue:

https://issues.jboss.org/browse/ERRAI-68

GAE Support for Errai is not feasible.

Is it not really feasible or there is a way to workaround:

- Errai UI would definitely work, since this is for GWT
- However the Errai bus, is there a workaround to make it work. Something like a wrapper?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am able to run Errai on the Google AppEngine Flex environment with no issues, however I am not using 100% of the Errai Framework. Even though erraiframework.org states that the latest version (4.0.0.Final) runs on JEE7, I had to compile with Java 8 to get it working properly (classes such as Marshalling are compiled in Java 8), hence the AppEngine Flex environment and not Standard.

This list (found here: https://developer.jboss.org/thread/233098) is also very helpful to see what AppEngine may support, and what it will not. Items with "no server dependency" should work because it's mostly client/GWT related libraries.

- Errai Bus: Any Servlet 2.x container (or 3.0 for async dispatch)
- Errai CDI container (without distributed events): no server
  dependency
- Errai CDI distributed events: Weld >= 1.1.5 and < 2.0
  (presently a hard requirement on Weld, not other CDI implementations)
- Errai Cordova wrappers: no server dependency
- Errai Data Binding: no server dependency
- Errai IOC container: no server dependency Errai
  JAX-RS in Jackson compatibility mode: no server dependency
- Errai JAX-RS with Errai Marshalling: any JAX-RS implementation plus
  errai-jaxrs-provider
- Errai JPA: no server dependency
- Errai JPA data sync: any JPA 2.0 or 2.1 implementation
- Errai Navigation: no server
  dependency Errai Validation: no server dependency
- Errai UI Templates: no server dependency